# Using JavaScript to change cursor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an MVC application and using Razor syntax.

I am using one `<div>` tag in a .cshtml file.

I want to use JavaScript to change the cursor icon to a hand when the cursor hovers over a particular `<div>` tag.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with CSS:

```
div.classname { cursor:pointer; }
```

If it must be done with JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    this.style.cursor = 'pointer';
});
```

Comment: Xander, although OP does not ask for JQuery, but may be it will be good if you add a jquery solution which is much cleaner than the javascript one.